# Creating new ActionBar Icons from eclipse

Tags: android

When i want to create an ActionBar icon using Eclipse's 'Create new Icon' and i choose the one i want from my resources.Instead of creating it correctly it only gets its shape and it paints it all grey. e.g  ifi have a round .png with an arrow inside,it only gets the round shape and not the arrow image.How can I overcome it?

**EDIT**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) (Chrome browser is required to use the tool) can automatically generate a number of different graphic assets for your app. It knows the right sizes for each icon type, for each Android version. Even better, this tool has been integrated into the Android Developer Tools (ADT) to allow seamless integration of new assets into your app.

Comment: I used it and it the same if i dit it from eclipse.

Comment: can you share me the image link?is it available over the net?if yes please share image link :)

Comment: share the link(the one with have arrow inside)

Comment: well that's the icon i was reffering to.The one with the arrow was as an example...

Comment: Make your image transparent and then try with android asset studio,It works well for me :)

Comment: how do i make it transparent?.PS it worked ok when i tried to do launcher icons.

Comment: well ask your designers to make the image transparent which you can use in your app easily :)